Plotly dots with different colors
I am trying to visualize branches and their customers on a map with a perimeter of a given radius. I want to keep the branch dot and customer dots with different colors. I have a dropdown menu for the branches so after selecting a branch the map is centered and zoomed on the selected branch. Then I need to see the branch and the customers with different colors. but so far, i could not manage it. the code is below, any help would be appreciated.
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from geopy.distance import geodesic

# Sample data
branches = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Branch A', 'Branch B'],
    'lat': [39.647868, 41.06212],
    'lon': [27.882012, 28.98888]
})

customers = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Customer 1', 'Customer 2', 'Customer 3'],
    'lat': [39.65113, 41.01879, 39.606046],
    'lon': [27.89559, 29.01249, 27.784534]
})

# Create a GeoDataFrame
branches_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(branches, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(branches.lon, branches.lat))
customers_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(customers, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(customers.lon, customers.lat))

# Function to create a circle
def create_circle(center, radius_km):
    angle_step = 10  # degrees
    angles = range(0, 360, angle_step)
    circle_points = [
        geodesic(kilometers=radius_km).destination((center.y, center.x), angle)
        for angle in angles
    ]
    return Polygon([(point.longitude, point.latitude) for point in circle_points])

# Define a perimeter in kilometers
perimeter_radius_km = 5

# Plot initial setup
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(
    lat=customers_gdf.geometry.y,
    lon=customers_gdf.geometry.x,
    hover_name=customers_gdf['name'],
    zoom=4,
    mapbox_style='carto-positron'
)

# Add all branch locations
fig.add_scattermapbox(
    lat=branches_gdf.geometry.y,
    lon=branches_gdf.geometry.x,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(size=12, color='red'),
    name='Branches',
    hovertext=branches_gdf['name']
)

# Add dropdown for selecting branches
buttons = []
for branch in branches_gdf.itertuples():
    branch_location = branch.geometry
    perimeter = create_circle(branch_location, perimeter_radius_km)
    customers_within = customers_gdf[customers_gdf.within(perimeter)]

    buttons.append(dict(
        args=[{
            'lat': [[branch_location.y] + customers_within.geometry.y.tolist(), [point[1] for point in perimeter.exterior.coords]],
            'lon': [[branch_location.x] + customers_within.geometry.x.tolist(), [point[0] for point in perimeter.exterior.coords]],
            'mode': ['markers', 'lines'],
            'marker': [dict(size=12, color='red')] + [dict(size=8, color='blue')] * len(customers_within) + [dict(size=0, color='blue')],
            'hovertext': [[branch.name] + customers_within['name'].tolist(), ['Perimeter']],
            'name': ['Branch and Customers', 'Perimeter']
        }],
        label=branch.name,
        method='update'
    ))
    buttons.append(dict(
        args=[{
            'lat': [customers_within.geometry.y.tolist() + [branch_location.y]],
            'lon': [customers_within.geometry.x.tolist() + [branch_location.x]],
            'marker': dict(size=8, color='blue'),  # Customer color
            'mapbox.center': {'lat': branch_location.y, 'lon': branch_location.x},
            'mapbox.zoom': 12
        }],
        label=branch.name,
        method='update'
    ))
    # Update the map center and zoom
    buttons[-1]['args'].append({'mapbox.center': {'lat': branch_location.y, 'lon': branch_location.x}, 'mapbox.zoom': 12})

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[{
        'buttons': buttons,
        'direction': 'down',
        'showactive': True
    }]
)

# Save the interactive map to an HTML file
fig.write_html("interactive_map.html")


You can use this code, I have made some minor changes to it so it should work fine
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from geopy.distance import geodesic

# Sample data
branches = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Branch A', 'Branch B'],
    'lat': [39.647868, 41.06212],
    'lon': [27.882012, 28.98888]
})

customers = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Customer 1', 'Customer 2', 'Customer 3'],
    'lat': [39.65113, 41.01879, 39.606046],
    'lon': [27.89559, 29.01249, 27.784534]
})

# Create a GeoDataFrame
branches_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(branches, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(branches.lon, branches.lat))
customers_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(customers, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(customers.lon, customers.lat))

# Function to create a circle
def create_circle(center, radius_km):
    angle_step = 10  # degrees
    angles = range(0, 360, angle_step)
    circle_points = [
        geodesic(kilometers=radius_km).destination((center.y, center.x), angle)
        for angle in angles
    ]
    return Polygon([(point.longitude, point.latitude) for point in circle_points])

# Define a perimeter in kilometers
perimeter_radius_km = 5

# Plot initial setup
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(
    lat=customers_gdf.geometry.y,
    lon=customers_gdf.geometry.x,
    hover_name=customers_gdf['name'],
    zoom=4,
    mapbox_style='carto-positron'
)

# Add all branch locations
fig.add_scattermapbox(
    lat=branches_gdf.geometry.y,
    lon=branches_gdf.geometry.x,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(size=12, color='red'),
    name='Branches',
    hovertext=branches_gdf['name']
)

# Add dropdown for selecting branches
buttons = []
for branch in branches_gdf.itertuples():
    branch_location = branch.geometry
    perimeter = create_circle(branch_location, perimeter_radius_km)
    customers_within = customers_gdf[customers_gdf.within(perimeter)]

    buttons.append(dict(
        args=[{
            'lat': [customers_within.geometry.y.tolist() + [branch_location.y]],
            'lon': [customers_within.geometry.x.tolist() + [branch_location.x]],
            'marker': dict(size=8, color='blue'),  # Customer color
            'mapbox.center': {'lat': branch_location.y, 'lon': branch_location.x},
            'mapbox.zoom': 12
        }],
        label=branch.name,
        method='update'
    ))

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[{
        'buttons': buttons,
        'direction': 'down',
        'showactive': True
    }]
)

# Save the interactive map to an HTML file
fig.write_html("interactive_map.html")

Here are the pictures:


